# reactive forms angular form group

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Why I can't write into the input before the set value?

**html**

```
<form action="" [formGroup]="titleForm">
    <input class="note-title" type="text" formControlName="title">
</form>
```

**typescript**

```
  titleForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup(
    {'title':new FormControl}
  );

    this.titleForm.patchValue({
      title:"hello"
    });
  }
```

the input value is successfully changed but I can't write into the input

Comment: typo `'title':new FormControl} use --> `new FormControl()`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p4qdvv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite formGroup to this

```
  titleForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl('')
  });
```